# Configuring .desktop Launcher (switcher problem)

Tags: unity, launcher

I am trying to write *.desktop launchers for 2 applications (Aptana and Dart Editor). I have the same problem with both of them. When I click on the icon, they launch properly but neither are they in Unity sidebar nor alt+tab. I just minimized one and can't open it again :D It's simply GONE! But working.

Here is what I have in aptana.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Icon[en_US]=/opt/AptanaStudio3/icon.xpm
Name[en_US]=Aptana Studio 3
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 /opt/AptanaStudio3/AptanaStudio3 -application com.aptana.commandline.launcher.LauncherApplication "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
Name=Aptana Studio 3
Icon=/opt/AptanaStudio3/icon.xpm
```

Can anyone spot the problem? The reason I don't just drag&drop the executable is because both, Aptana and Dart Editor, are just tweaked versions of Eclipse. If I did that, I would be able to launch application but then a second icon in the launcher would appear for editor's running instance.

Answer (score 1):

For `darteditor.desktop`, I'm using:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=DartEditor
GenericName=Text Editor
Exec=DartEditor
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=/home/richardworley/dart/icon.xpm
Categories=TextEditor;IDE;Development
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow
```

This is working with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> and minimizing to the sidebar.